# Properly designing an e-commerce database schema where a user can register products only if the user is a vendor

Tags: mysql

I am creating a simple e-commerce project where a user can sell products and a product can be sold by multiple users. I am attempting to design the database where i have a user table, user roles table, product table and a user_product table. So the user table is self explanatory that stores all users. Now i have user role table that will be defined by `client`, `vendor`, and `admin`. A user can register a product only if he or she is a `vendor`. So my question is should should i store the `id` from the `user_roles` table where he or she is defined as vendor in the `user_product` table or use the actual `id` from the `user` table.

So currently i have my database as:

```
create table `user` (
`id` bigint(20) not null auto_increment,
`firstname` varchar(100) not null,
`lastname` varchar(100) not null,
`email` varchar(255) not null,
`is_deleted` bit(1) not null default b'0',
primary key(`id`),
unique key(`email`)
);

create table `product`(
`id` bigint(20) not null auto_increment,
`name` varchar(255) not null,
`sku` varchar(255) not null,
primary key(`id`),
unique key(`sku`)
);

create table `roles`(
   `id` bigint(20) not null auto_increment,
   `name` varchar(100) not null
   primary key(`id`)
);

create table `user_roles` (
 `id` bigint(20) not null auto_increment,
 `role_id` bigint(20) not null,
 `user_id` bigint(20) not null,
 primary key(`id`),
 foreign key(`role_id`) references `role`(`id`),
 foreign key(`user`) references `user`(`id`)
);


create table `user_product`(
   `id` bigint(20) not null auto_increment,
   `vendor_id` bigint(20) not null,
   `product_id` bigint(20) not null,
   `description` text not null,
   `price` decimal(5,2) not null, 
   primary key(`id`),
   foreign key(`user_id`) references `user`(`id`),
   foreign key(`vendor_id`) references `user_roles`(`id`)
);
```

Comment: I don't see any good reason for the `vendor_id` column. Unless you define a `vendors` table.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel i intend to add vendor into roles table. So my intention is to check the `user_roles` table to verify if the user is a vendor or insert a vendor role into that table and using the `user_id` into the product table

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Also is the schema ok? What i mean is did i structure it correctly